# Why changing one array changes another array in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a two dimensional array namely States in C#. I build a one dimensional array, namely SubState, from States. When I change SubState, States changes too. I want States be unchanged. Thanks

```
int[] SubState = State [0];
SubState[0]-=1; //State[0][0] is also changed here
```

Answer (score 2):

`int[] SubState = State [0];` is just another reference to the `state` array and so can be changed via it as well.

What you probably want to do, is create a separate array from the `state` array like

```
int[] substate = new int[state.GetLength(0)];
state.CopyTo(substate, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

In my mind your State definition is:

```
int[][] State;
```

Array is a reference type and when you copy an element from the State array you get a reference to the array from the first list and the both references map to the same int[] array. So when you change array stored at SubArray you use a link to the same array.

The simple fix is a copy of the source array

```
var SubState = State[0].ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because when you assign the array you pass its reference you are not making a copy of it. Look at the msdn link on the array copy method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Array.Copy(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You are not building a new one-dimensional array.  You are simply creating a new reference to the first row of your two-dimensional array.  If you actually want to build a new one-dimensional array, you have to iteratively copy the first row of your two-dimensional array.

Try:

```
int[] SubState = new int[States[0].length];
States[0].CopyTo(SubState, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your element at position 0 of `State` is an array of `int` which is a reference-type. Thus both `SubState` and `State` reference the same array which is why changes to any of their elements are reflected by both. To overcome this problem you may create a copy of your `State`-array and copy its values to `SubState`:

```
States.CopyTo(SubStates, 0);
```

EDIT: Thius assumes that `SubStates` was already initialized with the same size as `States`. e.g:

```
int[] SubStates = new int[States[0].Length];
```

Comment: Thank everyone for very helpful comments.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
int[] SubState = State [0];
```

try

```
int[] SubState = new int[State[0].Length];
Array.Copy(State[0],Substate, Substate.Length)
```

So you are not simply assigning a new reference, but are actually copying the array correctly